# Invert The Sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

This is a question that was asked to me during an interview. For a Table like this (Which may have hundreds or thousands of records of this kind)

[image: Question Table]

what is the best way to revert the Seq so that A will be seq 4 and B will be seq 1 like this :

[image: Result Table]

I gave him the below query (*I used CTE Just to create the sample scenario. In the original case it was a table* ) :

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        Seq = 1,Nm = 'A'
    UNION
    SELECT
        Seq = 2,Nm = 'A'
    UNION
    SELECT
        Seq = 3,Nm = 'B'
    UNION
    SELECT
        Seq = 4,Nm = 'B'
)
SELECT
    Seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Seq DESC),
    Seq,
    Nm
    FROM CTE;
```

are there any alternative Dynamic queries of achieving the same in a more efficient way?

Comment: Seems pretty reasonable to me for a very contrived question.

Comment: Change the `UNION` to `UNION ALL` that's the only improvement that can be done in this query. Or if you can explain your original request we can see if there is any better way.

Comment: Don't bother about the Union. I wrote this just for checking the scenario. The actual input will be a table with the same structure

Comment: JayasuryaSatheesh We bother because matter so just take the advice. And as @Pரதீப் say, you cant improve that query anymore beside check indexes

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes, This is the best of my knowledge without making any design or structure changes in the tables side, But I just want to check if someone else has got something better than mine.

Comment: Well you have 3 users already agree with your query and 1 with one answer outside the box. Looks like you did well

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh This can be done using dynamic query but that will be lot worse when compared to your current approach

Comment: @Pரதீப், I said so during the interview but my Interviewer doesn't agree with me. So I just wanted to make it sure. That's all

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh Well the interviewer might be checking your confidence.

Comment: There is also another way to produce desired output. You can use `ABS(Seq - sqq - 1)` where `sqq` is maximal value in `Seq` column, but this solution need to get somehow maximum from `Seq` and to use function on `Seq` column, which can prevent usage of index.

Comment: Did the interviewer a better approach or just say that yours is not ideal? There are a number of ways to accomplish what is asked and yours is pretty much the most straight forward way to accomplish it. Anything else is just making a simple task more complicated and probably slower. I would be curious if they offered a better solution or if they are just terrible interviewers (there are lots of those out there).

Comment: I have added it as an informative post here : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47140468/invert-the-sequence/47140469#47140469

Comment: I marked your other as a duplicate. It is the same exact thing as this one.

Comment: Does the OVER(ORDER BY)-clause alone garantee the order of the result set or is an additional ORDER BY-clause required? `SELECT
    Seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Seq DESC),
    Nm
FROM mytable
ORDER BY Seq`

Comment: I thought QUestion and Informative questions are different and appear on different screens that's why I added one more. Thanks @SeanLange

Comment: **[Counterexample Demo](http://rextester.com/OGKT77699)** I hope you now understand interviewer.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Nope. Order isn't guaranteed unless you use `ORDER BY`

Comment: What is that @lad2025? The example is different to OP.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I am showing that this approach won't work, and he should use Gordon's suggestion.

Comment: @lad2025 I dont see how doesnt work. The sequence is inverted. And in that case the invert is the same as the original

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza So we see 2 different questions. I see the same as Gordon. Maybe incorrectly.

Comment: @lad2025 Invert the seq `AABB` --> `BBAA` that is why changing `A -> B` works

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Then this question/answer is still rubbish when you have gaps: **`1245` -> `4321`**.

Comment: In this case, the final `ORDER BY Seq` is missing from the OPs query. And also, the second `Seq` is superfluous. I would write it like in my first comment.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes You are right in both counts. But I guess the second Seq is for debug propose and the `ORDER BY` is only for the display. The request is invert the seq in the dataset not display in invert order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I save the count of the table to a declared variable, then I can subquery to get a reversed 2nd column.  The SQL Server Execution plan indicates the batch cost is less than with ROWNUMBER().

```
DECLARE @tablename TABLE(seq int PRIMARY KEY, Nm char(1))
INSERT INTO @tablename VALUES (1,'A'), (2,'A'), (3,'B'), (4,'B')

DECLARE @count int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tablename)

SELECT seq
      ,(SELECT Nm 
          FROM @tablename T2
         WHERE T2.seq = @count +1 - T1.seq) AS [Nm]
  FROM @tablename T1
```

Comment: That's the same that I have used here. What I'm looking for is there any other more efficient alternatives

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh Apologies, here's an attempt at a different algorithm

Answer (score 2):

How about?

```
select seq, (case when nm = 'B' then 'A' else 'B' end) as nm
from t;
```

Comment: That work, but I don't think that is the spirit of the interview question.

Comment: I don't think that's more efficient because if there comes another value, then you have to write one more case. What I want is a dynamic query like the one in the Question

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh he just answer your question, not hypothetical ones. Is up to you explain the requirements.

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh . . . It is only possible to answer the question that is asked.  The question seems pretty simple.  I wouldn't ask a question like this, but I definitely wouldn't think less of an answer that used `row_number()`, unless the question is specifically about the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: My Mistake I forgot to mention that this is just a sample case. I will update my question @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

An alternative query, not using an OVER-clause

```
SELECT
    (SELECT MAX(mytable.Seq) FROM mytable) - mytable.Seq + 1 As Seq,
    Nm
FROM mytable
ORDER BY mytable.Seq DESC
```

Comment: In my opinion, instead of calculating maximum `Seq` for each row, use `CROSS JOIN` to calculate it only once.

Comment: CROSS join can produce a huge amount of rows, where as a smart query optimizer can decide to exceute the sub-select only once. In fact the execution plan shows that the sub-select produces one row which is joined to the other rows. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/df363/9/0)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's appropriate to help with interview questions here, but since this one is so unrealistic, and there are so many complicated answers here, I pose this much simpler solution:

```
DECLARE @MaxSeq INT;
SELECT @MaxSeq = MAX(Seq) FROM Table;


UPDATE Table 
Set Seq = @MaxSeq - Seq + 1
```